# S3 limit to objects in a directory of a bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to save all of my images in a directory of a bucket. Is the number of objects in a same directory unlimited?

for example:

```
/imgs/10000000.jpg
/imgs/10000001.jpg
/imgs/10000002.jpg
....
/imgs/99999999.jpg
```

Comment: The total volume of data and number of objects you can store are **unlimited.** Check [this](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#How_much_data_can_I_store) FAQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no limit** on the number of objects stored in Amazon S3.

Amazon S3 does not actually have 'directories'. Instead, the Key (filename) of an object includes the **full path** of the object. This actually allows you to create/upload objects to a non-existent directory. Doing so will make the directory 'appear' to exist, but that is simply to make things easier for us humans to understand.

Therefore, **there is also no limit** on the number of objects stored in a 'directory'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the number of objects is unlimited. As John mentioned elsewhere, the entire S3 "file path" is really just one string internally, the use of the `/` as a path separator is just convention.

One suggestion I'd have to make use of this effectively is to name each image a ULID - https://github.com/ulid/spec - this gives you a couple of advantages:

- you don't need to worry about uniqueness, even if you put images in from multiple servers
- because the ULIDs are lexicographic and time based, you can query S3 directly to see which images were uploaded when (you can generate ULIDs for the start and end timestamp and call S3's [LIST](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) to get the images between them).
- it's easier to handle reports and metrics – you can easily find out which images are new, because they'll have a ULID after that period's timestamp.